# can't get logstash to create/populate an index in elastic search

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, centos, logstash

here's what i'm using:

```
CentOS 6.5 x64
Logstash 1.5.0
Elasticsearch 1.5.2
Marvel
```

all newly installed.

here's my logstash config file:

```
input {

file {

    path => "/home/datafeeds/public_html/myfeeds/datafeeds/completed/*.csv"
    }

}


filter {

csv {


    columns => ["z_md5","z_product_name_slug","z_country_code","z_product_name","z_expiry_timestamp","z_expiry_human","z_product_name_gb","z_description_gb","z_product_name_and_description_gb_md5","z_product_name_fr","z_description_fr","z_product_name_and_description_fr_md5","z_product_name_de","z_description_de","z_product_name_and_description_de_md5","z_product_name_it","z_description_it","z_product_name_and_description_it_md5","z_product_name_es","z_description_es","z_product_name_and_description_es_md5","feed_ID","feed_product_ID","feed_merchant_product_id","feed_merchant_category","feed_deep_link","feed_merchant_image_url","feed_search_price","feed_description","feed_product_name","feed_merchant_deep_link","feed_image_url","feed_merchant_name","feed_merchant_id","feed_category_name","feed_category_id","feed_delivery_cost","feed_currency","feed_store_price","feed_display_price","feed_data_feed_id","feed_rrp_price","feed_specifications","feed_condition","feed_promotional_text","feed_warranty","feed_merchant_thumb_url","feed_thumb_url","feed_brand_name","feed_brand_id","feed_delivery_time","feed_valid_from","feed_valid_to","feed_web_offer","feed_pre_order","feed_in_stock","feed_stock_quantity","feed_is_for_sale","feed_product_type","feed_commission_group","feed_upc","feed_ean","feed_mpn","feed_isbn","feed_model_number","feed_parent_product_id","feed_language","feed_last_updated","feed_dimensions","feed_colour","feed_keyword","feed_custom_1","feed_custom_2","feed_custom_3","feed_custom_4","feed_custom_5","feed_saving","feed_delivery_weight","feed_delivery_restrictions","feed_reviews","feed_average_rating","feed_number_stars","feed_number_available","feed_rating","feed_alternate_image","feed_large_image","feed_basket_link"]
    separator => ","

}

}



output {

elasticsearch {

    action => "index"
    host => "localhost"
    index => "products_test"
    workers => 1
}
}
```

i've double checked and there is a csv file in:

```
/home/datafeeds/public_html/myfeeds/datafeeds/completed/
```

i've CHMOD 777 the file just make sure it is readable.

i've tested my config file to make sure it's ok

```
$ sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --configtest -t -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/products.conf
$ Configuration OK
```

elastic search and logstash are running but no data is passed to elasticsearch or index created.

I've tried creating the index manually but no data is populated

I've tried rebooting the sever, stopping / restarting logstash / elastic search
several times.

this is the output from starting logstash in verbose mode:

```
sudo /opt/logstash/bin/logstash --verbose -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/products.conf
Using version 0.1.x input plugin 'file'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x codec plugin 'plain'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x filter plugin 'csv'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Using version 0.1.x output plugin 'elasticsearch'. This plugin isn't well supported by the community and likely has no maintainer. {:level=>:info}
Registering file input {:path=>["/home/datafeeds/public_html/shop.z/datafeeds/completed/feed_mydata_data.csv"], :level=>:info}
No sincedb_path set, generating one based on the file path {:sincedb_path=>"/root/.sincedb_fffe878b6c3eb92e792a8cceb1f1f170", :path= ["/home/datafeeds/public_html/shop.z/datafeeds/completed/feed_mydata_data.csv"], :level=>:info}
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:08 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode <init>
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] version[1.5.1],   pid[5042], build[5e38401/2015-04-09T13:41:35Z]
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:08 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode <init>
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] initializing ...
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:08 PM org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService <init>
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] loaded [], sites []
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:10 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode <init>
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] initialized
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:10 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode start
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] starting ...
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:10 PM org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService doStart
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] bound_address  {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9302]}, publish_address {inet[/<ip>:9302]}
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:10 PM org.elasticsearch.discovery.DiscoveryService doStart
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782]  elasticsearch/dvhITquLQBef1eA0pJVuFw
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:13 PM org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask run
INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] detected_master [Devil-Slayer][GeNlEqTkQu-UlSOzS7mStw][datafeeds-server.server.com]  [inet[/<ip>:9301]], added {[Devil-Slayer][GeNlEqTkQu-UlSOzS7mStw] [datafeeds-server.server.com][inet[/<ip>:9301]],[logstash-datafeeds-  server.server.com-4935-9782][LtNpHWk6SMGJLDRCXGQKFg][datafeeds- server.server.com][inet[/<ip>:9300]]{data=false, client=true},},  reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Devil-Slayer][GeNlEqTkQu-UlSOzS7mStw] [datafeeds-server.server.com][inet[/<ip>:9301]]])
Jun 06, 2015 1:35:13 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode start
 INFO: [logstash-datafeeds-server.server.com-5042-9782] started
 Automatic template management enabled {:manage_template=>"true", :level=>:info}
 Using mapping template {:template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*", "settings"=> {"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=> {"enabled"=>true, "omit_norms"=>true}, "dynamic_templates"=># <Java::JavaUtil::ArrayList:0x6fe472ee>, "properties"=>{"@version"=> {"type"=>"string", "index"=>"not_analyzed"}, "geoip"=>{"type"=>"object",  "dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}}}}}}},  :level=>:info}
New Elasticsearch output {:cluster=>nil, :host=>["127.0.0.1"], :port=>"9300-9305", :embedded=>false, :protocol=>"node", :level=>:info}
Pipeline started {:level=>:info}
Logstash startup completed
```

How do I get logstash to populate elasticsearch?

am I missing something?

Comment: If you specify the cluster name in the `elasticsearch` output, does make a difference? `cluster => [your_cluster_name]`

Comment: I added in: cluster => "elasticsearch" to the output, restarted logstash, restarted ES, checked logstash config - all passed but still no data or index in ES

Comment: Try just printing the events in your output rather than sending them to ES. `output { stdout { codec => rubydebug } }`. If this doesn't print stuff out, then the problem is upstream.

Comment: thanks pickypg, I tried changing the output as you suggested but nothing was outputted to the screen when I ran logstash again, where should I look next?

Comment: That implies to me that it's not getting _any_ events. The next thing I'd try would be to keep the debug output, but then to explicitly supply a known CSV file to see if that works.

Comment: yep i'm already referencing the exact file :( why the down vote? :(

Comment: By default Logstash will tail files. Is new data being added to any of the files?

Comment: DId you manage to solve this problem btw?

Answer (score 1):

When logstash newly discovers files, it starts at the end of them.  You need to add in `start_position` if you want it to start at the beginning:

```
file {
  path => "/home/datafeeds/public_html/myfeeds/datafeeds/completed/*.csv"
  start_position => "beginning"
}
```